# Resize Home without partition

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, home-directory, resize

I'm new on Linux but I already did resize of home partition using GParted, but I'm not having success to do this on Lubuntu.

On GParted I cant see the `/home` partition, only `/` and it has 5.97GB free but I can't use. 
Using "Baobab" I can see that `/home` has 20GB and its full.

So my question is, is there anyway to move this freespace from `/` to `/home` without lose data, format, or create a new disc?

[image: baobab pic]
[image: gparted pic]

Comment: There is nothing to move or resize, you have only one partition which holds your `/`-file-system including `/home`. You have still 6GB free space in this partition and I don't see why you should be unable to use this space.

Comment: @mook765 If I try to resize the virtual machine disk, maybe will it increase the size of `home`? or it'll continue as 20GB and just increment on `/` ?

Comment: If you increase the size of your virtual machine disk you will have to resize the `/`-partition afterwards. It's only one partition and the free space in the partition is available for all folders, including `/home`.

Comment: @mook765 Right, I did a clonedisk and resize 7GB, use another VM with GParted and I allocated the unallocated space. It didnt work because the `/home` still have 18GB used and max 20GB... What can I do?